# C# Linq to Sql обновление структуры базы данных

Tags: c#, linq2sql

Доброго времени суток. В DataContext есть методы CreateDatabase - создание БД и DeleteDatabase - удаление БД. Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли в Linq to Sql возможность обновления структуры базы данных?

Comment: Для этого обычно [используется механизм миграций](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591621(v=vs.113).aspx).

Comment: @AlexKrass, вы дали ссылку на миграции в EF. В Linq2Sql это будет работать?

Comment: @АндрейNOP по привычке думаю, что используется EF. Наверное нет, хотя должны работать ExecuteCommand в таком случае и можно обновить через него.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете использовать `SQLMetal.exe` для создания вашего файла dbml и / cs / vb. Используйте сценарий предварительной сборки, чтобы запустить его и указать каталог, в котором находится ваш проект `datacontext`.

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bin\x64\sqlmetal.exe 
/server:<SERVER> 
/database:<database> 
/code:"path\Solution\DataContextProject\dbContext.cs"
/language:csharp 
/namespace:<your namespace>
```

[Это оригинал на англиском](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40029/7198805)

Comment: Благодарю за информацию.